# Should I use PIPWIN or PIP for installing a library?

Tags: pip

I was wondering in which scenarios I can use `pipwin` instead of `pip`? I am aware that pip is the standard.

**From pipwin it states**

> pipwin is like pip, but it installs precompiled Windows binaries provided by Christoph Gohlke.

Does it offer any advantage if we are sharing our programs after packaging into a EXE with others - using windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` installs from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). `pipwin` installs from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Quite often there are more and better compiled wheels at the Christoph's Unofficial site.

Compare, for example, PyAudio (one of the most problematic packages, see how many question [there are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip+pyaudio)). At PyPI there're currently [wheels](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/0.2.11/#files) for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.6. At the Christoph's Unofficial site there are [wheels](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.10.

The bottom line is: always consider Christoph's Unofficial site and `pipwin` when `pip install` failed to install a package for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My personal situation:

I tried to install the pyaudio package using the tradinatiol pip command and I have some errors, at the end, using pipwin I could install the pyAudio and for my application (record voice and speech recognition) works fine.

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score -1):

As the description says here https://pypi.org/project/pipwin/

pipwin installs unofficial python package binaries for windows provided by Christoph Gohlke

Always trust the official sources and don't go for unofficial resources especially while working on enterprise applications. Please use only pip